# Android Emulation + vServer ? Windows 2016 Server

Tags: android, emulation, windows-server-2016

i have a Windows 2016 Server on a vServer and want to run android on it.
Which version ist almost irrelevant. Should be at least Android 4 if possible ;)

I tried MANY MANY Emulators, VirtualBox with Android_x86 images, Android Studio and so on.

I can't get it to run!

Mostly it is because of following things:

1. The Emulator won't work with Hyper-V (which isn't even installed?!?!)
2. The Emulator says i have to enable Virtualization. 
   Which i can't, cause there is no BIOS to go to on a vServer.
3. It says i have no Hardware Graphics Acceleration
   or my Graphics-Drivers are to old.
4. Just won't finish the installation at all!

So, what i need is a functioning vServer (doesnt matter if Linux or Windows) with a way to install Android on it. Not toooo difficult! Because i have, at beste, lower intermediate knowledge with linux. To get it to work in Windows would be a dream!

I hope some can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't run Android on Windows.  Both are OSes.  So I assume you mean the Android emulator.

The emulator is a virtual machine that requires hardware emulation.  Because of this, it can't be run on top of another emulator.  It doesn't matter what the OS its on is, you need to run it directly on real hardware, not on a VM.

Comment: Yeah , thats what i meant. The emulator, sry ;)

ok, so if i want it to have online, i have two options:

a. Rent a root server or
b. Host it on my own (or others) PC and configure a remote connection

Am I right?

Comment: I'd be careful of anything you rent, as most cloud machines are VMs, and may not have HAXM instructions enabled in the BIOS.  You may want to look into services like AWS Device Farm if you must do things remotely.  Or at least ensure that the device you're renting will support HAXM instructions.

Comment: Ok, I will look for that stuff when I search for a new server.

Thank you very much for that information!