# Xamarin Emulator on Windows Server 2019

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, android-emulator

I am developing an application in `Xamarin Forms` and I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I try launching the emulator, `Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo`, from my server, it says,

> Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo on Hyper-V needs Windows Hypervisor
>   Platform installed.

I checked the features for the server and `Hyper-v` is enabled.

How this can be fixed?

Comment: Have a look at this document[Hardware acceleration for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) may help you.

Comment: `Hyper-V` is separate from `Windows Hypervisor Platform`. Check Windows features to see if Windows Server 2019 supports WHPX.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT This is a EC2 machine, I am not sure if HAXM helps or not.

Comment: @JonDouglas WHPX does not appear as an option in windows features.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555947/android-emulation-vserver-windows-2016-server) maybe help.

Answer (score 11):

Run this command in the command line as administrator:

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature:HypervisorPlatform
```

It will enable the Windows Hypervisor Platform on the windows 2019.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The feature isn't available within the Windows Features dialog but running this command enables the required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following command in `powershell` in order to activate the missing windows feature:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "HypervisorPlatform" -Online
```